# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray). in making prediction dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have dataset and trying to make sliding window for prediction.

```
    X_train = []
    Y_train = []
    for i in range(15, 3000, 1):
        X_train.append(dataset[i-15:i, 0])
        Y_train.append(dataset[i:i+15, 0])

    return np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train)
```

but error occurs,

ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

how can i do for that?

here is the full detail of error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3444, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "", line 1, in 
runfile('C:/Users/Monet/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/training2.py', wdir='C:/Users/Monet/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1')
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
File "C:/Users/Monet/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/training2.py", line 304, in 
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=MY_EPOCH, callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback, earlystopping],
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py", line 102, in convert_to_eager_tensor
return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

Comment: can you update full details of the error (at which line the error occurs and snippet of code around that line of code?)

Comment: Did you try out ```torch.Tensor(np_array)``` for the transformation?

Comment: I tried `tf.convert_to_tensor(y)` instead.

Comment: Often this error is caused by a 'ragged array', A 1d array (or list) containing arrays or lists that differ in shape.